# TreeView — selected node style doesn't appears to selected node

Tags: asp.net, html, css

My code is :

```
            <asp:TreeView ID="TreeViewCategories" runat="server" ExpandDepth="0" Style="min-height: 200px;
                max-height: 500px;" LineImagesFolder="~/TreeLineImages" NodeIndent="0" LeafNodeStyle-CssClass="LeafNodesStyle"
                CssClass="TreeView" NodeStyle-CssClass="NodeStyle" ParentNodeStyle-CssClass="ParentNodeStyle"
                RootNodeStyle-CssClass="RootNodeStyle" SelectedNodeStyle-CssClass="SelectedNodeStyle"
                LeafNodeStyle-Width="100%" NodeStyle-Width="100%" ParentNodeStyle-Width="100%"
                RootNodeStyle-Width="100%" Font-Size="12pt">
                <Nodes>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="All Items" SelectAction="Expand" PopulateOnDemand="True" Value="All Items" />
                </Nodes>
            </asp:TreeView>
```

css

```
.TreeView  
{
    border-bottom:1px dotted #B2B2B2 !important;
}

.TreeView div
{
    margin-left:5px;
}

.TreeView table
{
    border-top:1px dotted #B2B2B2 !important;
}

.TreeView div table
{
    border-bottom:none !important;
    border-top:none !important;
}

.TreeView table td
{
    padding:2px 0;
}

.LeafNodesStyle 
{

}

.RootNodeStyle 
{

}

/* ALL ELEMENTS */

.NodeStyle 
{

}

.ParentNodeStyle 
{
    /*background:yellow;*/
}

.SelectedNodeStyle { font-weight: bold; color:#6799D1; display:block; padding:2px 0 2px 3px; }
```

so I see (with firebug) for my selected node appears Visited style , node style , leaf style but not Selected node style :(

How to fix this HTML/CSS/ASP to make selected node Bold and Blue for example ?

Thank you.

added : adding nodes like here :

```
            foreach(c : Category in rootCategories)
            {
                mutable newNode : TreeNode = TreeNode(c.Title, c.Id);
                newNode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.SelectExpand;
                newNode.NavigateUrl = "Items.aspx?catId=" + c.Id.ToString() + "&lvl=0";
```

solved with...

```
categoryId : string = Request.QueryString["catId"];
n : TreeNode = findNode(categoryId, TreeViewCategories.Nodes, lvl);
n.Selected = true;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ***SelectAction*** attribute on the *asp:TreeNode* is Expand change it to ***SelectExpand***.
This ensures that there is a postback and the tree control is redrawn to apply the seleceted node style that you set on the treeview

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeViewCategories" runat="server" ExpandDepth="0" Style="min-height: 200px;
        max-height: 500px;" LineImagesFolder="~/TreeLineImages" NodeIndent="0" LeafNodeStyle-CssClass="LeafNodesStyle"
        CssClass="TreeView" NodeStyle-CssClass="NodeStyle" ParentNodeStyle-CssClass="ParentNodeStyle"
        RootNodeStyle-CssClass="RootNodeStyle" SelectedNodeStyle-CssClass="SelectedNodeStyle"
        LeafNodeStyle-Width="100%" NodeStyle-Width="100%" ParentNodeStyle-Width="100%"
        RootNodeStyle-Width="100%" Font-Size="12pt">
        <Nodes>
            <asp:TreeNode Text="All Items" SelectAction="SelectExpand" Value="All Items">
                <asp:TreeNode Text="All Items" SelectAction="SelectExpand" Value="All Items" />
                <asp:TreeNode Text="All Items" SelectAction="SelectExpand" Value="All Items" />
                <asp:TreeNode Text="All Items" SelectAction="SelectExpand" Value="All Items" />
            </asp:TreeNode>
        </Nodes>
    </asp:TreeView>
```

Comment: Thank you , but it doesn't helped . . . :( maybe becuase of NavigateURL on nodes ?

Comment: even if I do <asp:TreeNode Text="All Items" Selected="true" SelectAction="SelectExpand" PopulateOnDemand="True" Value="All Items" /> it doesn't appears :(

Comment: Not sure why it doesnt work for you, i tested it out by adding some nodes directly in the markup. I am editing my answer to add the mark up

Comment: ok... since u have a navigation url specified, on selecting a node you will be redirected to that page (items.aspx) so how do you expect the tree to persist selected node. Can you explain a bit more on what you are trying to implement, we might be able to come up with something which might not require specifying a navigation url

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that `<NodeStyle>` attributes takes precedence over `<SelectedNodeStyle>` attributes.

For example, I had:

`<NodeStyle Forecolor="Black"/>

    <SelectedStyle Forecolor="Blue"/>

    <Nodes>

    <asp:TreeNode Text="RootSub1" Value="1" Selected="true"/>

    <asp:TreeNode Text="RootSub2" Value="2" Selected="false"/>

    </Nodes>`

My `Rootsub1` and `RootSub2` appeared both with black forecolor. I then removed the `ForeColor="Black"` attribute from the NodeStyle properties, and violà, there was a difference in styling.

My advice is to workaround this flaw, avoid duplicate attributes, I'll continue using this method until I find a better solution, but so far till date everybody on the net is stuggling.

Answer (score 0):

In your `CSS`, replace

```
a.SelectedNodeStyle { background:#6799D1; color:#6799D1; display:block; padding:2px 0 2px 3px; }
```

with

```
.SelectedNodeStyle { font-weight: bold; color:#6799D1; display:block; padding:2px 0 2px 3px; }
```

And in your `ASPX`, replace

```
SelectedNodeStyle-ForeColor="RoyalBlue"
```

with

```
SelectedNodeStyle-CssClass="SelectedNodeStyle"
```

Comment: Do your items have a NavigateURL?

Comment: @nCdy, Firebug should show something like `class="TreeViewCategories_0 NodeStyle TreeViewCategories_1 LeafNodesStyle TreeViewCategories_7 SelectedNodeStyle TreeViewCategories_9"` on the selection.  Not seeing it?

Comment: can't see SelectedNodeStyle on Firebug :( And yes - my items have a NavigateURL.

Answer (score 0):

css:

```
    .SelectedNodeStyle {
    padding-left: 3px!important;
    padding-right: 3px!important;
    font-size: 110%;
    background: none !important;
}
```

asp.net:

```
<asp:TreeView runat="server" SelectedNodeStyle-CssClass="SelectedNodeStyle" ...
```