# ASP.Net TreeView with SiteMap is ignoring Node.Selected

Tags: asp.net, treeview, sitemap, selected, treenode

I create have a TreeView bound to a SiteMap. It works great.

```
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" />
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1">
</asp:TreeView>
```

Now I want to change the way the selected node looks.

```
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" />
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1">
    <NodeStyle ImageUrl="~/Images/Page.png" />
    <SelectedNodeStyle ImageUrl="~/Images/Page_Hot.png" />
</asp:TreeView>
```

The thing is, the current page is not automatically selected on the tree (why MSFT, why?). This is not the end of the world. So, I created a little code behind like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack) 
        return;

    TreeView1.TreeNodeDataBound += new TreeNodeEventHandler(TreeView1_TreeNodeDataBound);
}

void TreeView1_TreeNodeDataBound(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
    var _CurrentUrl = Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
    e.Node.Selected = (e.Node.NavigateUrl == _CurrentUrl);
}
```

But still the node is not selected. My gut tells me it's the wrong event.

Any help?

Thanks // Jerry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is really annoying. I suppose the "technical" answer to my question is that it worked all along. However, the real issue is that ImageUrl in the SelectedNodeStyle appears to be ignored. I am going to paste a little more of my solution so you can see what I have, but no matter what I try, ImageUrl in the SelectedNodeStyle is ignored.

(PS: .Net4)

```
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" />
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" ShowExpandCollapse="false">
    <NodeStyle ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="true" NodeSpacing="5" HorizontalPadding="5" 
        ImageUrl="~/Images/Page.png" />
    <SelectedNodeStyle Font-Bold="true" NodeSpacing="5" HorizontalPadding="5" Font-Underline="true" 
        ImageUrl="~/Images/Page_Hot.png"/>
    <HoverNodeStyle ForeColor="Navy" />
</asp:TreeView>
```

Comment: Maybe what this question has to say, might be related. Check that your nodes are set to "SelectExpand" or "Select". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455570/treeview-selected-node-style-doesnt-appears-to-selected-node

Answer (score 0):

The AbsolutePath vs the NavigateUrl might be suspect, one is a relative path (NavigateUrl) and the other, as the name implies, is an absolute path.  If you run in debug mode can you see that the two values are indeed the same?

Comment: Yeah, they match; I do not think that is it.