# Asp.net 4 TreeView SelectedNodeStyle ImageUrl seems to be ignored

Tags: asp.net, treeview, imageurl

I have the following code and no matter what I try to do, it seems the ImageUrl on the SelectedNodeStyle is ignored. Am I doing something backwards?

Note that this thread is a continuation of [ASP.Net TreeView with SiteMap is ignoring Node.Selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313042/asp-net-treeview-with-sitemap-is-ignoring-node-selected/6332520#6332520) which asked a different question and revealed this new question.

```
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" />
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1">
    <NodeStyle ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="true" NodeSpacing="5"
        HorizontalPadding="5" ImageUrl="~/Images/Page.png" />
    <SelectedNodeStyle Font-Bold="true" NodeSpacing="5" 
        HorizontalPadding="5" ImageUrl="~/Images/Page_Hot.png"/>
    <HoverNodeStyle ForeColor="Navy" />
</asp:TreeView>
```

In the sample above, the selected node underlining works just perfectly. However, the image never changes. Yes, I double-checked the image was named correctly. It changes the other style attributes, just not the image. Quite frustrating.

Solution?

Comment: I want to point out that setting this in code behind works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug and goes back a few years (~2005, 2006).  (Excuse the link-filled answer)

http://forums.asp.net/t/943367.aspx
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/104297/treeview-selectednodestyle-imageurl-not-working

I would set it in code-behind instead.

Comment: You avatar is funny - the youngest developer ever!